# Howto: Outlook 2016 for Mac - Debugging/View Console Logs in Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office365-apps, officedev, office-2016

We develop an **Outlook app (now called add-in) using html5/js** originally for OWA but now it is targeted to all Office Supported Platforms.
And indeed, it seems to work on all  platforms (ios, safari on mac, windows browsers and outlook) **except for Outlook 2016 for Mac**.
When running inside Outlook 2016 for Mac it behaves very strangely. Not loading half the times, and when loading, it does not work properly.

We find it very hard to find the problem. We did not **find a way to debug our scripts or even see our console logs**.

Do you have any flags/procedure/tools that we can use, so that we can see what's going on with our add-in in this platform?

Answer (score 1):

1. open your add-in on outlook.
2. go to and open one of: 
       32-Bit – C:\Windows\System32\F12\F12Chooser.exe
       64-Bit – C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\F12Chooser.exe

and there is your debugger.

visit [here](http://toddbaginski.com/blog/how-to-debug-office-add-in-in-office-clients-without-visual-studio/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn818897.aspx

Also review all API objects, methods and properties you are accessing against the API documentation; note the Support Details section at the bottom of the member's page to confirm its availability for Outlook for Mac.

To debug it against Outlook for Mac, you may need to use the Yeoman tool:

http://dev.office.com/blogs/creating-office-add-ins-with-any-editor-introducing-yo-office

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vorlon.js to be able to debug your add'in.

You should definitively take a look at VorlonJS here :

http://vorlonjs.io/

In a nutshell, VorlonJS is an open source, extensible, platform-agnostic tool for remotely debugging and testing your JavaScript. Powered by node.js and socket.io.

You launch your add'in in "whatever you want" and then you can debug it in VorlonJS