# Outlook AddIn : How to show console.log with Outlook Desktop?

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am working on an Outlook AddIn in JavaScript. My functionality works well in Outlook Web but it isn't working in Outlook Desktop.

In Outlook Web I can see my console.log messages in the console of the browser. But I can't figure out how to do this with Outlook Desktop so I can properly debug my Desktop app.

Comment: As an alternate, then you can use Fiddler or debug addins using developer tools on Windows 10. Here's the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: yes this is it thanks, i found it in an other answer actually https://stackoverflow.com/a/53139447/9675031

Comment: What if I don't want to use a task pane. Is that a nonsensical approach in general, or are there other ways how to debug that properly?

Comment: I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73333763/get-console-log-of-side-loaded-outlook-add-in-without-task-pane for that specifically, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open your add-in in Outlook.
2. Go to and open one of:

   - 32-Bit – `C:\Windows\System32\F12\IEChooser.exe`
   - 64-Bit – `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\F12\IEChooser.exe`

and there is your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10 and Outlook use Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj?activetab=pivot:overviewtab. I have just used it today with outlook addin

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate, you can use Fiddler or Procmon or debug addins using developer tools on Windows 10. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10).