# Get console log of side-loaded Outlook Add-in without task pane

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

This question is related to [Outlook AddIn : How to show console.log with Outlook Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109100/outlook-addin-how-to-show-console-log-with-outlook-desktop).

So, what I want is to have an Add-in that just does some automation with launch events and doesn't use a task pane (also see [Create an Outlook Add-in without a task pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73333814/create-an-outlook-add-in-without-a-task-pane) about this).

Maybe that is a bad idea in the first place, please tell me if so.

However, in this setting, viewing the log with tools described here [Outlook AddIn : How to show console.log with Outlook Desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65109100/outlook-addin-how-to-show-console-log-with-outlook-desktop) doesn't work.

Is there a way to view the log, or a suggestion how I can get notified of problems during the code execution (including printing some values for debugging)?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the debugger from VSCode and go through each line tracking intermediate results instantly. See [Debug your event-based Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/debug-autolaunch) for more information.

The output window will display your `console.log` statements.