# Create an Outlook Add-in without a task pane

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I want to create an Outlook Add-in that doesn't require a task pane, but just performs some automation based on launch events.

Is this possible? The yo office generator has an option to only generate a project with manifest, but there seems to be a lot of additional required stuff missing afterwards.

Should I go with a generated task pane Add-in structure instead and just remove unneeded things from it instead? I am not that experienced in web development, so I am looking for an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

Yes, it is possible. Task panes are not required for running Office web add-ins.

> Should I go with a generated task pane Add-in structure instead and just remove unneeded things from it instead?

You may scaffold any project the yeoman generator suggests and remove all the unnecessary stuff from there. Ready-made generated skeletons are made for your convenience. But don't forget to update the manifest file in such cases, not only delete unnecessary files from the `src` folder.

You may find the [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch) guide helpful.

Comment: Thanks! So, it is easier to scaffold projects than to just generate a manifest project and add required things to it manually?

Comment: Well, I sometimes scaffold a more precise solution and then remove some things. It depends.

Comment: Alright! Then I will figure that out on my own.